# NodeJS trouble sending messages to client

Tags: node.js

I am trying to learn Node.JS, but making a REST API using this tutorial: 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2

I am having a very stupid little issue I can't seem to fix. In my user_routes.js file, I am trying to write several messages to the express() app, however it never works after the first res.send() call. Why is this? I can't find anywhere in my code where I am closing the connection or whatever, so why can't I write more than once to the request?

My user_routes.js

```
    module.exports = function(app, db) {
    app.post('/user', function (req,res) {
        res.send("User Request Recieved via POST");

        // Add the user to the database, if they don't already exist
        const firstName = req.body.firstName;
        const lastName = req.body.lastName;
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;

        const user = {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName : lastName,
            email : email,
            password : password
        };

        if (db.collection('users').find({'email':email}).count() == 0) {
            res.send('Unique Email');
            db.collection('users').insert(user, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error");
                } else {
                    console.log(result.ops[0])
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.send("Email already in use")
        }

    })
};
```

Any my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 6969;
const db = require('./config/db')

// We need to decode data from the url using the body-parser lib
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

MongoClient.connect(db.url).then( function(db) {
    require('./app/routes')(app, db);
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log('We are live on ' + port);
    });               
}).catch (function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});     


module.exports = app;
```

I don't seem to close the connection anywhere, so why is it I am only able to write one message to the client?

Answer (score 1):

res.send() is the last thing your function should be doing. Think of it like a return for your function, you can't return multiple times.

Comment: @DtrollMC This isn't a problem in node.js. The client asks a "question" to the server and the server needs to serve it one response. Otherwise the client wouldn't know when the server is done responding.

If you have a more complex message to send, you should be appending  an object with all the information.

This is how most functions in most languages work.

Answer (score 0):

## res.send() == return()

res.send() is equivalent to "return" for your post -- you can only do it once per call.

## Multiple Messages per res.send()

If you want to send multiple messages through one call, you need to compile an object/array of messages you want to send and send that object/array through your res.send(). Example:

```
ret_msg = [];
ret_msg.push("Here's your first message.");
ret_msg.push("Here's your second message.");
ret_msg.push("Here's your third message.");

res.send(ret_msg);
```